# To enable bluetooth tethering in android programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an android app that silently enables and disables the bluetooth tethering
without asking from the user.I have founded the solution but it requires user interaction.
does anyone knows how to enable it silently.Please help me with your suggestions.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I dont think it is possible without user interaction. Even if it is possible today, then I am sure google developer will close that security point soon.

Comment: but i have done the same for wifi tethering. That's why i think that this will also be possible in case of bluetooth.

Comment: Well I am just telling you my experience. My colleagues has developed a code that was programmatically enable/disable GPS ( not start/stop ). But Now in Kitkat version that security loop-hole is totally closed. That's why I am saying the code you are developing may not work in near future.